# No data found showing on page loading in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying some data, so while the page is loading, "No data found" control is working, what should I do to prevent this ? 
Here is my code

```
 <ul id="owl-example" class="list-unstyled topContributors">
                    <li ng-show="TopContributors.length==0">
                        <p><span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">No Contributors....</span></p>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-repeat="contributors in TopContributors">
                        <img ng-src="{{contributors.AccountName}}" />

                        <div class="contName">
                            <p>{{contributors.UserName}}</p>
                        </div>

                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: Where is 'no data' defined? Perhaps in a function that loads TopContributors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a flag to hide "No Contributors...." until the request is not completed

```
<li ng-show="TopContributors.length==0 && flag">
  <p><span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">No Contributors....</span></p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the below code is enough to achieve what you want rather than adding a flag:

```
<li ng-show="TopContributors && TopContributors.length==0">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller (written in es6, but you get the drift):

```
export default class MyController extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super(arguments);
    this.loading = true;
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    // Assumes data loaded correctly;
    someCodeLoadingData();

    this.loading = false;
  }
}
```

In your template:

```
<li ng-show="TopContributors.length === 0 && vm.loading === false">
  <p>No Contributors....</p>
</li>
```

Put your styling in a stylesheet, keep your templates clean. The vm (in my case at least) comes from our Base where vm = this;

Answer (score 0):

Use can use ng-cloak to achieve this in case data is not coming from an API using AJAX call. Basically it will wait for the variable to load before performing any function on that div or element
Add ng-cloak to your ng-show statements as shown below:

```
<ul id="owl-example" class="list-unstyled topContributors">
    <li ng-show="TopContributors.length==0" ng-cloak>
        <p><span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">No Contributors....</span></p>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="contributors in TopContributors">
        <img ng-src="{{contributors.AccountName}}" />

        <div class="contName">
            <p>{{contributors.UserName}}</p>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

In your css file write:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
 display: none !important;
}
```

If it is coming using an AJAX call, you can setup a flag while the call is in progress and update it when you achieve success.

Comment: Have u actually tested this? How is ng-cloak supposed to know that this variable was actually loaded? what if its happening thru a promise that takes a bit to load? My impression for ng-cloak is that you use it for other purpose, this taken from the angular docs: "used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading."

Comment: The ng-cloak directive prevents the document from showing unfinished AngularJS code while AngularJS is being loaded.

AngularJS applications can make HTML documents flicker when the application is being loaded, showing the AngularJS code for a second, before all code are executed. Use the ng-cloak directive to prevent this.

Comment: I get how ng-cloak works, its recommended for prevent flickering while templates are being loaded/compiled, however, OP hasn't shared with us his js code so we just have to make assumptions as to how he is loading the TopContributors variable. If that is coming from a backend service - which will be async - then angular's ng-cloak won't be effective as most likely the templates will be loaded and compiled way before his service gets resolved and his variable gets updated. Also, are you sure u need that CSS override for ng-cloak? Isn't that by default?

Comment: No ng-cloak works in conjunction with that CSS you can. Check this for details https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak  Also your argument that it wont work for async calls, that is correct and for that you can setup a flag. But OP has not shared that so I did not recommend doing that unnecessarily.

Comment: Updated my answer as per the discussion.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the documentation. It says: "ngCloak works in cooperation with the following css rule embedded within angular.js and angular.min.js" That means the CSS code right after this statement is *already* in their code, you only need to add that code if you are dealing with CSP (Content Security Policy) which is necessary when developing things like Google Chrome Extensions or Universal Windows Apps (most likely not OP's situation).

Comment: But I have tried this a lot of times in my own code and ng-cloak was not working without that CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

The usual suggestion here recommends adding a variable for loading status. I don't think you even need that.

Besides adding ng-cloak to avoid template loading flickering, I'd suggest you default your TopContributors variable to a negative value, this way will ensure your div isn't displayed while you wait for it to load it (from a backend service I'd assume). Example:

```
function topContributorsController(...) {
    $scope.TopContributors = -1; // 'not loaded' state
```

And here is the change to your template to add ng-cloak:

```
<ul id="owl-example" class="list-unstyled topContributors" ng-cloak>
```